Reach out to Quarkus
I think this page on https://quarkus.io/support/ could lead to support issues on the site. We already had this post today LTS should have it's own major version
Can someone from the community management side reach out to have them address the standard "outsourcing" problem?
The current text on that page reads:

Ask your questions on Stack Overflow. After the documentation, it’s probably the best place to look for answers. We actively monitor the quarkus tag.

Some guidance would be to "Ask your on-topic questions on Stack Overflow, otherwise use the GitHub Discussions".

Hum..., and the Quarkus Tag Wiki is just a Copy&Paste of the Marketing stuff from the 'Quarkus' Site itself..., this doesn't meet SO Guidelines about Plagiarism for Tag Wikis etc...!

"Ask your on-topic questions <...>" is equally bad. People won't magically know what's on-topic. On topic to whom, even?

That page probably shouldn't recommend to "Ask your questions ..." in the first place. Looking for existing questions, sure, but no amount of promo speak on such a posh page is going to prepare people for asking on SO.

There are a lot of people out there who would like to answer their product's questions here, it seems. We really should review and revise our guidance for those cases.

"Ask your questions on Stack Overflow. After the documentation, it’s probably the best place to look for answers. ". Man. Everything that page says, is WRONG. No you do not unconditionally ask your questions on Stack Overflow and you don't go looking for answers there either. You use Google, Bing or DuckDuckGo to search for your answers and PROBABLY Stack Overflow will pop up in the top X search results.
